# Eclipse [Desktop NO-HEAD]

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Beside my project name says [Desktop NO-HEAD] in eclipse. I am developing an android application, and was wondering if there is anything wrong with this, why it might be saying that, and if it makes a difference to anything, though everything seems to compile and debug normally. Surprisingly, I have found literally nothing online about this. I was just wondering if anybody knew, thanks!

Comment: Are you using a git repository and the eclipse plugin egit? If so, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896533/git-no-head-statement might help you. It most likely has to do with version control anyway.

Answer (score 12):

You apparently have some type of version control going on.  Right click on yoir project and go to Team.  If you don't want to see it and/or don't want to have any version control at the moment there should be an option somewhere there in Team to disconnect.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, for git, in Eclipse Team settings, I had to *Disconnect* and then *Share Project* (Right-click project -> Team -> Disconnect / Share Project...) with the following settings:

[image]

Checking any other permutation of those check boxes caused the NO-HEAD for me.